# Loading multiline text from database to TextArea

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have some multi line text saved in MySql database (VARCHAR 255). When i load it, and process it using standard php function "nl2br", it echoes fine (multi line). But, when i load multi line text from database, make it "nl2br" and then send it to javascript (so it gets displayed in textarea), it won't be displayed! What's wrong?

```
echo "<SCRIPT>FillElements('".$subject."','".$text."');</SCRIPT>";
```

P.S.
FillElements function:

```
function FillElements(Sub,Txt)
        {
            document.getElementById('txtSubject').value=Sub;
            document.getElementById('txtMessage').value=Txt;
        }
```

Comment: How do you send it to JavaScript?

Comment: Simple, like this: echo "<SCRIPT>FillElements('".$subject."','".$text."');</SCRIPT>"; $text is nl2br-ed before that.

Comment: It works if text IS NOT multiline, otherwise it won't work

Comment: @guest I assume that nl2br-ed means that the string contains `"<br>"` parts in it... right?

Comment: Well probably, text user types in textarea is stored in database, and then when i try to load it from database and show it again in textarea it won't work. I do believe then "nl2br" converts "\n" to "<br>".

Comment: @guest Have you tried without nl2br-ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textarea`s don't actually store the contents in an attribute like `value` in the same manner as input elements. They actually store the contents in in between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags. Meaning that the contents is actually treated as CDATA in the document.

```
<textarea>
    This is my Content
</textarea>
```

Produces a text area with "This is my Content" as the contents.

The implication of this is that you cannot use the code you have to alter the contents of a textarea. You have to alter the innerHTML property of the textarea. I have set up a simple example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wFZWQ/

---

As an aside, since you are populating the fields using PHP on the creation of the page, why not merely fill the data in the HTML markup, this seems like a long way round to do it.

Also, since you don't appear to be using it, have you seen [jQuery][1] it abstracts alot of things out, so instead of typing `document.getElementById("the_id")` to get an element you can use CSS selectors and merely write `$("#the_id")` to get the same element. You also get a load of useful functions that make writing javascript mucxh easier.

[1]: http://jquery.com jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Newline tags (`<br />`) don't cause actual new lines in `<textarea>`.

You can pass the "real" newlines (`\n`) to your `<textarea>`, though.

I created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UPpCM/) for that.

---

**EDIT:** For the updated `FillElements` code:

```
$subject = "String\nWith\nMultiple\nLines";

printf('<script type="text/javascript">FillElements(%s)</script>',
   json_encode($subject)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but even if i don't change nl to br (nl2br method), even then it won't work... :\

Comment: Is `FillElements` actually filling the textarea?

Comment: Posted! @Linus yes, it does but it works only if text is in single line

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your HTML source code looks like this:

```
<script>FillElements("foo","foo
bar
baz");<script>
```

Correct?

In JavaScript, strings cannot span multiple lines...

Comment: No, it doesen't look like that, but second param is taken from database where it's placed as multiline. So, how can i show multiline text from database in my textarea? Darn web programming! :\

Comment: @guest How does it look like then? Post it

Comment: Just like this: echo "<SCRIPT>FillElements('".$subject."','".$text."');</SCRIPT>"; (it's all in a single line). $text is loaded from database (standard php database methods). Basically user types something in textarea, php saves that text into database, and later when i try to load that text back to textarea, it won't if contains newline

Comment: @guest No, that is your PHP code. How does the resulting HTML source code that is sent to the browser look like? Open your page in a browser and view the source (right click -> view source code)